# How to build boost with zlib support?

Tags: c++, boost, zlib, boost-iostreams

I'm trying to build Boost C++ libraries version 1.65.1 on Windows with zlib support. I'm using zlib library from Conan package with zlib which I built previously. I'm trying to understand the right steps for building boost with zlib support to use them for creating Conan recipe for boost. I tried to follow the instructions from the official boost [documentation](http://www.boost.org/build/doc/html/bbv2/reference/tools.html#bbv2.reference.tools.libraries.zlib). I set the environment variables `ZLIB_LIBRARY_PATH`, `ZLIB_NAME`, and `ZLIB_INCLUDE` the following way:

```
set ZLIB_LIBRARY_PATH=C:\Users\ivan.bobev\.conan\data\zlib\1.2.11\igsoft\stable\package\63da998e3642b50bee33f4449826b2d623661505\lib
set ZLIB_NAME=zlibstat
set ZLIB_INCLUDE=C:\Users\ivan.bobev\.conan\data\zlib\1.2.11\igsoft\stable\package\63da998e3642b50bee33f4449826b2d623661505\include
```

and the build command is:

```
.\b2.exe -j8 --prefix="C:\work\test_builds\boost\install\x64_shared_release" --build-dir="C:\work\test_builds\boost\build\x64_shared_release" --layout=system architecture=x86 address-model=64 toolset=msvc variant=release debug-symbols=on link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared install
```

The result was:

```
 - zlib                     : no  (cached)
```

I also tried to clear boost build cash between runs.

After this I tried to set the environment variables directly from the `b2` build command:

```
.\b2.exe -j8 -sZLIB_LIBRARY_PATH="C:\Users\ivan.bobev\.conan\data\zlib\1.2.11\igsoft\stable\package\63da998e3642b50bee33f4449826b2d623661505\lib"-sZLIB_NAME="zlibstat" -sZLIB_INCLUDE="C:\Users\ivan.bobev\.conan\data\zlib\1.2.11\igsoft\stable\package\63da998e3642b50bee33f4449826b2d623661505\include" --prefix="C:\work\test_builds\boost\install\x64_shared_release" --build-dir="C:\work\test_builds\boost\build\x64_shared_release" --layout=system architecture=x86 address-model=64 toolset=msvc variant=release debug-symbols=on link=shared threading=multi runtime-link=shared install
```

The result was the same.

Finally I tried adding the options into `project-config.jam` file the following way:

```
using zlib : 1.2.11 : <search>C:\Users\ivan.bobev\.conan\data\zlib\1.2.11\igsoft\stable\package\63da998e3642b50bee33f4449826b2d623661505\lib <name>zlibstat <include>C:\Users\ivan.bobev\.conan\data\zlib\1.2.11\igsoft\stable\package\63da998e3642b50bee33f4449826b2d623661505\include ;
```

Again I have no success.

In the zlib include folder there is subfolder zlib. I also tried the 3 variants from above setting the path as "../include/zlib". No success again.

How to build Boost with zlib support using my pre-built Conan package with zlib?

Comment: Who maintains the boost conan package? Most likely you should directly ask them whether `zlib` support is a feature (or check docs)

Comment: @seha I'm trying to create my own Conan package with Boost. In the official Boost Conan package GitHub repository there is open [issue](https://github.com/lasote/conan-boost/issues/42) because currently the support for zlib is not implemented properly.

Comment: Okay. So really what you want is to know how to build boost with zlib from your system. That has nothing to do with Conan (except you happened to have installed/built zlib from the conan package)

Comment: Yes. I will remove Conan tag from the question.

Comment: Is the library you get from Conan actually named `zlibstat`?

Comment: @llonesmiz I'm using my Conan recipe for the zlib library and this is the name which I use and which is in the corresponding `ZLIB_LIBRARY_PATH` directory.

Comment: It seems that patching the project-config.jam and injecting the paths to the dependencies works. Take a look to the modified recipe for 1.64.0: https://github.com/lasote/conan-boost/blob/testing/1.64.0/conanfile.py 
And let me know if it works. (Method: patch_project_jam)

Comment: With the project-config.jam It seems to work on Linux/OSX but not in Windows where zlib keeps deactivated. In Linux/OSX the include dir passed to the compiler looks good. (pointing to the zlib/bzip2 packages). I assume you are trying with Windows. Right?

Comment: @lasote Yes, I'm trying it with Windows. I will try the solution in your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `project-config.jam` patch is ok, and actually, is working in Linux and OSX. In Windows you need to replace the "\" characters (escape char in jam language) with "/".

You can see my updated Conan recipe for Boost 1.64.0 [here](https://github.com/lasote/conan-boost/blob/b350c3b4939c12fd577c5ad85db162b3842f047f/conanfile.py#L266)